# HTML, text and input, to go up

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint

I have this HTML code:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
             <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>
                    Titel
                    <span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                </nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>Textkörper</nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New"/>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Body" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Body')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Body" ControlMode="New"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" >
            <H3 class="goup1">
                <nobr>Läuft ab</nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Expires" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Expires')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="Expires" ControlMode="New"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Textkörper have big input and "Läuft ab" is going a lot down.

How can I go up with "Läuft ab"? Some help with code please.
Here I've aded aded a new code so you can see full code. Thank you

Comment: All the inputs in your snippet have the same size. It is unclear what your problem is and what you are asking. Also, **do not use tables to visually arrange non-tabular content**. The last time this was a valid way to do html died with Netscape 4.7 - or for HTML e-mails that have a very low common denominator when it comes to standards support. And in e-mails you don't use form elements...

Comment: Yes but this is sharepoint and Textkörper input is biger.

Comment: No, it's not. At least not in Chrome or Firefox. What "browser" are you using? This code example is so goddamn faulty, it would take me half an hour to explain all that's going horribly wrong in the code.

Comment: Here I've added the right code, because I wanted to reduce the code that is why it was the last code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and use margin attributes. That way you could influence the distance between two components.